# How to get search results quickly?

Tags: java, android, search, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database of objects in the firebase database, and I need a function to return some search results; if I receive a string to search the "Title" aspect of objects for some substring, I need to return a list of all of the objects which satisfy that. I'm currently doing it exhaustively, i.e. checking each book's field and adding it to the list.

Unfortunately, this method has terrible speed: as the list grows larger, the time it takes to generate this list is unacceptably large. An acceptable solution, however, would be to return the objects one at a time, so as to grow the list dynamically. It occurs to me that normal search features seem to use this, and video/audio buffering must be getting that data continuously as well.

But I can't figure out how to implement this in Java, on Android. Just nothing even similar has come across me, but I'm sure there's a way to do it. Any suggestions?

**EDIT: ** So sepcifically, I have an adroid app on which I need to write a function for my partner to use. This function must gather Book data objects and return them. I only have 32 books in the database currently, so I assume that the any sink in time I experience is due to getting the data from firebase. There must be some way to due it one resulting book at a time, to lessen the perceived wait time for the user, but I have no clue as to how to approach this.

Comment: Have you tried using a heap instead of a list? I assume order doesn't matter to you

Comment: @Meepo Hmm, haven't heard of them. After looking into them just now, I don't quite get what they are or how they can help me; is the explanation quick or am I in over my head here?

Comment: It's like a list but the indexing is done for speed. So you can store and retrieve things fast in a heap with the disadvantage that they are not ordered. Since adding and getting from a heap is much faster than a list, I suggest you try it, although I'm not sure if it helps for really really really large amounts of data. The explanation of how it works is a little complicated, but using it should be easy. Let's say you add 123, 245 and 357 to a heap. If the heap is say 10 ints long, then the ints you store would be stored at the index number mod 10. Something along those lines

Comment: also note that I'm referring to the data structure and not the heap that your computer has. Your search results may be talking about the wrong thing. For instance, a priority queue is a heap: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html

Comment: Hmm, I think that would work if the list itself were the problem. Unfortunately I think the bigger time sink is the actual getting of data from Firebase, which I can't really see how to optimize other than return results as they are collected.

Comment: Yeah I think we need some more information to answer the question. Sorry I couldn't be of help.

Comment: I'll edit the question and see if I can be more specific about my situation.

Comment: I know that your question was answered, but the problem with using an arrayList is that it has the illusion that it is expanding, but really what's happening is that as the list gets bigger, it has to be copied into a bigger list causing a slow down. That's why I thought something like a HashSet or some Heap could help you, and it probably would make it significantly faster.

Comment: @Meepo Since the books don't exactly have a 'value' and I don't need them in any order, shouldn't there be a faster method than a heap? With heaps, I would have to manage where child nodes are with each addition; should I just use a bog-standard array instead?

Comment: why would you have to manage the child nodes? I though you just wanted to simply print the results and you can do that with a for loop with HashSet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160381/discussion-between-vedvart1-and-meepo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the orderByChild method provided by the Firebase sdk. This is a sample code:

```
  titlesDatabaseReference.orderByChild("title").equalTo("the title you search for").
              addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            //Do whatever you want with the snapshot
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

You can also use the limitToFirst and limitToLast methods to limit the search results.

Comment: Is there a convenient way to use this in a returnable function? I know it's asynchronous, and I'm not too familiar with Java's handling of async and promises and such.

Comment: You can use a callBack interface, and implement it in the class you want (Main Activity for instance) then you call it inside the onDataChange method.

Comment: I mean like this:
public interface CreateAccountCallback {
    void onSearchDone();
}